# Real-time video "buffering" to html5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video, streaming, real-time

I am working on a broadcasting software, using the server-client model.

Video+audio data is captured in the broadcaster's browser using [getUserMedia](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html) and [MediaRecorder](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/) APIs. The data is chunked every ~200ms using setInterval and sent to the server via WebSockets.

The server will then broadcast the received blobs to a list of receiver clients.

The receiver has a `<video>` element whose source is set to a [MediaSource](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/) object, which has a `sourceBuffer` element and data is appended to it every time the client receives data from the WebSocket server.

The problem is that the video doesn't actually play and it stays in a state of constant buffering and it only shows the very first frame that it receives. I can however play each chunk received (both audio and video) by resetting video source to the url created for each blob and then calling `video.play()`, so the data is received and broadcasted by the server is intact. (mind you, this "buffering" method has a very unpleasant side-effect: video element flashes white every time `play()` is called).

Here is the code for the receiver

```
var ms;
var sourceBuffer
var video;
var serverAddress = 'ws://localhost:8000';
var socket;

$(document).ready (function(){
    video = document.getElementById('rendered_video');
    ms = new MediaSource();

    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(ms);
    video.play();

    ms.addEventListener ('sourceopen', function(e) {
        sourceBuffer = ms.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"');
    }, false);

    socket = new WebSocket (serverAddress);
    socket.onopen = function () {
        socket.send ('receiver');
    };

    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function(e) {
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(e.target.result);
        };
    // Convert blob to ArrayBuffer
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.data);
    }
});
```

I know that the APIs I'm using are fairly new and they are incompatible with a lot of browsers, but I'm just looking to create a small demo for now.

**Edit**: I realized that there is something off on the broadcaster's side. The way I recorded data via `MediaRecorder` was to call `start()` when streaming starts, then once every 200ms call `stop()` then `start()` again so the `ondataavailable` would trigger. This encodes captured stream in specified mimetype and send to server. Playing each chunk separately worked because each chunk is a proper video+audio container, and the problem comes when trying to concatenate multiple containers in a single buffer. Still trying to find a workaround to this.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, both on Firefox and Chrome. I'm guessing either the spec doesn't support this, or we're doing it wrong. I'm looked at all the API methods/properties, and searched for example code, but haven't found any solution. Calling play() on the video, and/or setting sourceBuffer.timestampOffset doesn't seem to help.